# Hide Panel unless shortcut is pressed on KDE

Tags: kubuntu, kde5, autohide

I'm using KDE's autohiding abilities for my main "taskbar" panel and love the distraction free experience.

However, I often struggle with accidentally showing it by moving my mouse too close to the screen edge because e.g. I'm trying to select the last line in a terminal or click on a link at the bottom of a website.

Is there a way to force the panel to be hidden and only show it manually via a shortcut?

I'm on Kubuntu 22.04 with KDE Plasma 5.24.7 (kwin also 5.24.7, which I believe is what I'd need to wrestle with?), KDE Frameworks 5.98.0,